# How to get valid result from table.get using Dexie/IndexDB

Tags: javascript, dexie

I'm a PHP coder so not fully in the know with Javascript so possibly making a real schoolboy error here. I'm trying to facilitate some client side DB using Dexie & IndexDB. I can get values in using db.table.put and retrieve them all using db.table.toArray. However I seem to be struggling with getting individual records back out again. I'm trying to query for Keydata based on a form input. Heres my code, but it returns a TypeError cannot read property of undefined.

Here I can confirm in line 4 that my 'search2' variable contacts keyData (e.g. 1). But when used in line 5 it doesn't return a valid result. Can anyone see the issue?

```
      function searchData(){
          var search2;
        search2 = document.getElementById('search2').value; 
          alert ("Id " + search2);
          db.contacts.get(search2).then
        (function (contact) {
            alert ("Id " + contact.id + " : " + contact.title + " " + contact.forename + " " + contact.surname);
          }).catch(function(error) {
         alert ("Ooops: " + error);
      });
      }
```